# Http2 PushPromise Access Denied Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, http2, azure-web-app-service, push-promise

HI I have the below piece of code for Enabling PushPromise for Http2.0 clients.

```
public static IHtmlString StyleSheet(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string contentPath)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.PushPromise(contentPath);

    TagBuilder linkTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("link");
    linkTagBuilder.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    linkTagBuilder.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Content(contentPath));

    return new HtmlString(linkTagBuilder.ToString());
}
```

This was all working fine till last friday, after which i started getting Access Denied Exception.

We have hosted our site on Azure App service for more than a year now!!

[image]

Any ideas as to why this failed after an year?